# color deconvolution: use custom stain matrix from Image-J with scikit-image

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, imagej

I want to use `scikit-image "stain_separation"` method with a custom stain matrix.
I have used the color deconvolution plugin from `Image-J` to create a custom matrix. 
When I use these values, the stain separation does not work at all (all channels look the same after devonvolution. When looking at built in stain matrices e.g. `"hdx_from_rgb"` they have a different range and contain also negative values, while Image-J outputs are all positive and in the range 0-1. Do I have to rescale my Image-J values somehow before they are compatible with `scikit-image`?

Or maybe the easier question. How do I create a stain matrix for color deconvolution from scratch using just `scikit-image`?

Thanks,
Mario